# Converting SMO Data Types to SqlDataTypes

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I am using SMO to compare one database against another.

This compare utility is NOT using drop and replace type of logic, It's using ALTER statements.

So, when I compare one column against another and they are not equal, I need to generate an Alter statement.

In order to generate that Alter statement, I need to convert the `Column.DataType` to something in the realm of SQL.

I've been looking but haven't found anything that will convert a DataType into an `SQL DataType` string. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You mean you need something like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
DataType p = new DataType() ;
p.SqlDataType = SqlDataType.NVarChar;
p.MaximumLength = 200 ;
```